# CSS Grid - Massive bottom margin shows up below my images

Tags: html, css, css-grid

After checking my grid on mobile there's a massive bottom margin shwoing up below my div. I'm not sure what's causing this. Here's an image of what I mean:

[image]

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 40px 40px;
  max-width: 100%;
  @include for-tablet--large {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="activation-square__title" data-activation-square="1"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/activation-square-1-title.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="activation-square__title" data-activation-square="2"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/activation-square-2-title.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="activation-square__title" data-activation-square="3"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/activation-square-3-title.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="activation-square__title" data-activation-square="4"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/activation-square-4-title.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="activation-square__title" data-activation-square="5"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/activation-square-5-title.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="activation-square__title" data-activation-square="6"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/activation-square-6-title.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="activation-square__title" data-activation-square="7"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/activation-square-7-title.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="activation-square__title" data-activation-square="8"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/activation-square-8-title.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="activation-square__title" data-activation-square="9"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/activation-square-9-title.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="activation-square__title" data-activation-square="10"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/activation-square-10-title.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div>
    <h3 class="has-text-color" style="color:#fb61a6">
      Title here
    </h3>
    <div class="wp-block-buttons">
      <div class="wp-block-button">
        <a class="wp-block-button__link has-background-color has-text-color has-background" href="#" style="background-color:#63d9cd">ACCESS NOW</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);` will resize all rows to the largest row and cause a margin therefor. Remove the line or repalce it with: `grid-auto-rows: auto;`

Comment: What is your intended number of rows and columns (for desktop and for mobile size)?

Comment: Please post enough code (including the image files) so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tacoshy was right. It's solved. I just removed `grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);` altogether

Answer (score 0):

Tacoshy was right. It's solved. I just removed `grid-template-rows` altogether and the problem went away.